# How to insert value of checked checkbox in array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, input

I want select all input values that is `checked` and has name `DisbursementUnitCodes`

```
$('input:checked[name=DisbursementUnitCodes]').val()
```

This code give the first element value but i want give all input value to list or array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to iterating selected elements and get value of its.

```js
var arr = [];
$("input:checked[name=DisbursementUnitCodes]").each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="DisbursementUnitCodes" value ="A" checked />
<input type="checkbox" name="DisbursementUnitCodes" value ="B" />
<input type="checkbox" name="DisbursementUnitCodes" value ="C" checked />
<input type="checkbox" name="other" value ="D" checked />
<input type="checkbox" name="other" value ="E" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` gives you value of first element in selection. If you want all values in array, you should use `.map()` like this:

```
var values = $('input:checked[name=DisbursementUnitCodes]').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
```